# What does the apostrophe here mean in the set?(it's not "complement")

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

[Explanation from a book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkwNg.jpg)

So after some googling I found out that the apostrophe in a set means "complement" but in this example it must mean something else right?
Aside from that, I have not seen any explanations of the apostrophe in this use case.

"$x$ and $x'$ are distinct elements of $X$" so I wanna know what this $x'$ is.

I've also encountered this kind of notation in another book in a similar case. (something about "bijective")

I'm really sorry that I'm not able to formulate this question any better. I will learn how to formulate it using the tools in my future questions.

Thank you for your time and patience in explaining.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $x'$ is an element of $X$ distinct from $x$.  You could write $y$ instead of $x'$, though that would be confusing, because it's an element of $X$, not $Y$

Comment: Note that it's not quite an apostrophe, because in most professionally typeset works an apostrophe is curved while the mark on $x'$ is straight. If I were reading a passage with $x'$ aloud, I would say "$x$ prime". The same symbol is used in at least three completely different ways, and sometimes you can only tell what it means by reading the explanation in the _same text._ Later in this particular text, we are told that even though $X$ is a set, $X'$ is not the complement of $X$; instead, $X'$ is just another set that is a little bit different from $X.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the author's way of denoting two arbitrary (distinct) elements of the set $X$. Other options could be:

"$x$ and $x^*$ are distinct elements of $X$"

"$x_1$ and $x_2$ are distinct elements of $X$"

"$x$ and $y$ are distinct elements of $X$"

"$a$ and $b$ are distinct elements of $X$"

"$\tau$ and $\tau'$ are distinct elements of $X$"

You get the idea. Any choice of two distinct symbols would work, as long as those symbols haven't been used already for something else. Beyond this, it's purely a matter of taste and style on the part of the author.